Grass r.resamp.stats Outputs no data where there is data in the original raster
I am very new to working with QGIS and geospatial data. I am working with a raster data set that I have generated externally and loaded into QGIS. The original raster is high resolution but very sparse. The majority of cells are 'no data' with discrete tracks of data running through it. My goal in QGIS is to resample the original raster to a lower resolution to 'fill in' the gaps without actually interpolating.
In the Grass toolkit in QGIS, I found r.resamp.stats which apparently does exactly what I am needing. As I understand it, it generates a lower-resolution raster where the value of each cell is some statistical aggregate of the corresponding cells in the original raster. This has worked for me before, but on this data set, I am getting areas where the resampled raster reports 'no data' but there is clearly data in that area in the original raster. I have added a picture below of such an area. The large purple pixels are the resampled raster and the tracks of smaller black pixels are the original raster.

Could anyone provide some insight into why those cells have ended up empty in the resampled raster? I imagine it has to do with how sparse the original raster is, but I think it should be able to report a value as long as there is at least one pixel with data in the original raster in that area. Is there some setting or argument that I can pass to make that happen?
